# Relationship through Matrix field

Tags: matrix, relations

I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around [Relations](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations) through a [Matrix](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/matrix-fields) field.

I have a [Structure](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/sections-and-entries#section-types) called `exhibitors`.

I have a Matrix field on a Page called `rooms`, This has one block type `room` and within that block there is an entries relationship field called `exhibitors`.

What I'm wanting to do is loop through the `exhibitor` entries and for each one, I want to find the first room they are related to via the matrix field.

I've tried various flavours of the `relatedTo` method, but I just can't seem to get them related, I just get null back from every one I've tried.

Here's an example of one I've tried:

```
{% set exhibitors = craft.entries.section('exhibitors').order('title') %}

{% for exhibitor in exhibitors %}
    {% set room = entry.rooms.relatedTo({
        sourceElement: exhibitor,
        field: 'room.exhibitors'
    }).first() %}

{{ room }} <-- Always a null entry

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks as though I was overcomplicating things! All it needs to be is this:

```
{% set exhibitors = craft.entries.section('exhibitors').order('title') %}

{% for exhibitor in exhibitors %}
    {% set room = entry.rooms.relatedTo(exhibitor).first() %} 

    {{ room }} <-- No longer a null entry

{% endfor %}
```